# jQuery change one of a number of class names for an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation, classname

I have a dynamically changing layout based on twitter bootstrap. It is a grid, with grid items that look something like this:

```
<div id="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 red"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6 yellow"/>
    <div class="span6 green"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

Depending on user interaction, I need to be able to find items with a certain span class (i.e. span6) - and change it to a different span name (i.e. span4). I won't necessarily know what the span name that I'm changing is ahead of time, I just know it will start with "span" and that everything after that will need to be removed and appended with the new number. How do I do this in jQuery without clearing out the class names entirely?

In other words, I need to do some sort of find

```
([class*="span"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to iterate through each element and iterate through the class list of each element and check for "span", replacing the class if so. You can do that like so:

```
$('.row div').each(function () {
    var $object = $(this);
    $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function (i) {
        // If you want particular span classes to become new classes
        if(this.toString().indexOf("span3") >= 0) {
            $object.removeClass(this.toString());
            $object.addClass('special'); // New class to be added
        }
        // If you want all classes with "span" in them to become a new class
        else if (this.toString().indexOf("span") >= 0) {
            $object.removeClass(this.toString());
            $object.addClass('span1'); // New class to be added
        } 
    });
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kvmmQ/2/). This also includes an alternative method that strips the end of each class to get the same result

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#grid .span6').toggleClass('span4 span6');
```

This will remove the class `span6` and add the class `span4` to all elements with the `span6` class inside the grid

[You can read more about the toggleClass method here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Update based on revised question:

I presume that the interaction you are mentioning will involved an element with one of the "span" classes and that the interaction is a jQuery event - i can't know since the question is too vague, but with these assumptions, the following should work:

```
function interactionHandler(e) {
 var newSpanName = '<put the span name you wish to switch to here>',
     spanName = this.className.replace(/(?:^|.*\s)(span\d)\(?:s.*|$)/,'');

 $('#grid .'+spanName).toggleClass(newSpanName + ' ' +spanName);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention - I won't necessarily know that the class of the div is span6. It could be span1,span4,span12, etc. So I won't know which class to toggle

Comment: in that case you should probably restate your question so that it can be answered... because right now i have no idea what it is you want :P

Comment: @mheavers: i have updated the answer, but i am afraid the question is still far to vague that i can promise the solution you are looking for, you might want to be a bit more specific in the future when you ask questions - it's simply easier to help you that way.